# Java simplify code

Tags: java

i have a beginners question:

I have 3 Classes extending Thread. They are doing the same job: open a ServerSocket and then wait for connections in a while loop. The only difference between these classes is, that they start a specific Thread when they have a connection.
I want to simplify this and have one Class doing the job, that atm 3 classes are doing. In the example the only difference is the call of SocketThread1, SocketThread2 and SocketThread3.

How could i make 1 class instead of having 3 of them?

Example:

```
\\class 1

public void run()
{
    while(true)
    {
        Socket s = serversocket.accept();
        new SocketThread1(s).start();
    }}

\\class 2

public void run()
{
    while(true)
    {
        Socket s = serversocket.accept();
        new SocketThread2(s).start();
    }


}

\\class 3

public void run()
{
    while(true)
    {
        Socket s = serversocket.accept();
        new SocketThread3(s).start();
    }
```

Comment: So your classes extend Thread but launch new threads in their run method... That is a little confusing. Can you show more code?

Comment: What is there in SocketThread1,SocketThread2SocketThread3 Post it

Comment: Yes, the classes extend Thread and lunch new Threads in the run method :)

Comment: @VishalVijay its not about whats in SocketThread1-3 ... sorry, i know the question was some kind of confusing

Answer (score 1):

Why not to implement an Interface (or parent class) for SocketThread 1,2 and 3 and then pass just an instance of this interface and call its start() method?

EDIT: I mean something like this: (the code is not tested and should be adapted to your requirements)

```
public class SocketThread1 implements SocketThread{...}
public class SocketThread2 implements SocketThread{...}
public class SocketThread3 implements SocketThread{...}
public class YourClass implements Runnable{
private SocketThread thread;
public YourClass(SocketThread thread){
    this.thread = thread;
}
public void run()
{
thread.start();
}
}
```

Comment: I don't see how it helps. He/she needs a mechanism for creating new threads for new clients. 3 fixed instances won't be enough.

Comment: He/She wants to reduce the code in one class and the only difference that I see between the classes is that they are calling 
new SocketThread**X**(s).start(); So why not to call just socketThread.start(); where socketThread is an instance of one of SocketThread1,2 or 3 and all of them are children of the interface SocketThread. Doing it so you don't need 3 classes anymore

Comment: As I understand the problem, the server has a main loop that creates a new thread per new connection. Your solution seems to have only one instance associated with the server class. A thread instance can be started only once.

Comment: @iberbeu - better.  I would go with one thread class that has three methods.  You can recycle the threads easier, should you so wish.

Comment: @EyalSchneider you're right, anyway for achieving that goal you only need to adapt a bit the code. My solution with the interface would still be acceptable

Comment: @MartinJames - your solution could also be possible but I think mine is prettier ;)

Comment: @iberbeu - prettier maybe, but be careful you don't end up looking like a tart :)

Answer (score 0):

You can have one Server class, that receives a SocketThreadFactory in the constructor.

Alternatively, the Server can be abstract, where subclasses should implement the createClientHandlerThread(Socket) method:

```
public abstract class Server extends Thread {
    private ServerSocket serverSocket;

    public Server(int port) throws IOException {
        serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port);
    }

    public void run() {
        try {
            while (true) {
                Socket s = serverSocket.accept();
                createClientHandlerThread(s).start();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO: handle the exception
        }

    }

    protected abstract Thread createClientHandlerThread(Socket s);
}
```

Now define three (or more) simple subclasses, that only deal with the creation of the thread for a given socket.

Comment: I don't think this solution has enough abstract polymorphic class interfaces